# How to call a method of an object returned from an async function without parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

I got this function:

```
async def download(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                return resp
```

To get the data, I'd need to write:

```
text = await (await utils.download(url)).text()
```

How to change `download` so I can write like this

```
text = await utils.download(url).text()
```

without getting `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'text'`?

Comment: You cannot. Because of how it is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help simplifying the usage:

```
async def download(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                return await resp.text()
```

Then to use it:

```
async def main():
    text = await download("http://python.org")
```

Comment: Yes, but I also want to call read() or json() or get some attribute

Comment: @DleanJeans not sure that's possible as is, if I understand correctly the need. But you could tuple the results you need, if you know in advance what is needed: 
In download: return await resp.text(), await resp.read()
In usage: text, read = await download(url)